# How to implement erase on vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, containers

Learning from `Accelerated C++: Practical Programming by Example`, in chapter 11, there was an implementation (only with basic features) of vector container from STL. After that was an exercise for implementing `erase` function just as std::vector does. What I have tried:

```
#include <memory>
template<class T>
class Vec{
private:
   T *data;
   T *avail;
   T *limit;
   std::allocator<T> alloc;
   ...

public:
   explicit Vec(size_t n, const T &val = T())
   {
      create(n, val);
   }
   T *const begin()
   {
      return data;
   }
   T *const end()
   {
      return avail;
   }
   T *erase(T* const pos);
   ...
};

template <class T>
void Vec<T>::create(size_t n, const T &val)
{
    data = alloc.allocate(n);
    limit = avail = data + n;
    std::uninitialized_fill(data, limit, val);
}

// here I am trying to implement the erase function with 3 pointers (data, avail, limit)
template<class T>
T* Vec<T>::erase(T *const i)
{
   if(i==end())
   {
       return end();
   }
   else if(i >= begin() && i < end())
   {
      size_t member = i-data;
      size_t size = limit-data;
      T* new_data = alloc.allocate(size);
      std::uninitialized_copy(data, i, new_data);
      T* new_avail = std::uninitialized_copy(i+1, avail, i);
      data = new_data;
      avail = new_avail;
      limit = data + size;
      return &data[member];
   }
   else
   {
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Now If I want to check, if that function works correctly:

```
#include "vec.hpp"
int main()
{
    Vec<int> v(5, 2);
    if (v.erase(v.begin()+2))
    {
        for (int i:v)
        {
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I get

```
...
0
0
0
0
Segmentation fault
```

I have somehow made infinity allocation-loop, but I have no idea how. Anyway, How can I make the erase function (or in another words, how to shift elements after the erased one to left), via `std::uninitialized_copy`?

EDIT:
the whole class definition is there:

https://www.codepile.net/pile/rLmz8wRq

Comment: As written, `erase` shouldn't compile. It uses the name `i` that doesn't appear to be declared anywhere.

Comment: Your `erase` function also leaks memory and is very unusual in that it allocates memory when *removing* an element. Removing an element from an array should not require allocation

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/z68P5G). There are many problems in this program, but none of them manifest the way you describe. If you would like further assistance, prepare a [mcve].

Comment: @Igor I have edit, I hand copy it. The pos argument shouls be i.

Comment: Like I said, the code you show doesn't exhibit the problem you claim you have. Show the code that does.

Comment: @unholy, I have no idea how otherwise, without allocation, perform new array without the element. I do not know how simply "shift" whole element to another address. How otherwise should I make it?

Comment: You don't use `new_data` for anything anyway. You just allocate it, copy some data to it, and then leak it without ever looking at it again. If you simply drop the two lines that mention `new_data`, the behavior of your program won't change in any way (well, except it won't leak).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik see the edits

Comment: `new_avail` still points into the old buffer, not the new. So now you have `data` and `avail` pointing into unrelated arrays. And, you leak the old buffer (the one `data` used to point to).

Comment: this doesn't match complexity of true `erase`. The actual one just copies "tail" of array over the "erased" elements, if necessary and changes `end()` iterator value. This is no way even close to STL (or ISO) vector, they place distinction between reserved and used storage (also they avoid using naked pointers for iterator to make code less fragile).

Answer (score 0):

Here you create new storage for vector:

```
 T* new_data = alloc.allocate(size);
```

and here you write to array pointed by argument, which (supposedly) points to location on old storage. `new_avail` would point to old storage.

```
 T* new_avail = std::uninitialized_copy(i+1, avail, i);
                                                    ^ that's destination
                                        ^ that's source
```

Then you even leak memory:

```
 data = new_data;   // old storage pointed by data is lost along with the "tail" of array
```

After this vector state is completely broken, pointer arithmetic go to undefined area:

```
 avail = new_avail;  // avail points to old storage, data points to new one.
                     // (data < avail) no longer guaranteed to be true
```

Because in all likelihood `data` would be greater than `avail`, you don't get an infinite loop, you may get a very long one. OR may not. Attempt to iterate through vector after this "erase" amounts to Undefined Behavior.